# Android-Device and Emulator cannot reach an internal Web-Server

Tags: android, android-networking

I have a Web-Server http://my-server.com in my network which cannot be reached with my android device and android developer. The Web-Server is only accessible in my network, so I can open pages from my desktop pc but the android devices cannot find the web server when i try with their browser.

Are there any DNS Settings which I can adjust so that the devices can reach my server?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest your WLAN on the phone is active :-). Try the direct IP Adress, some DNS-Server in Routers and Android don't like each other.

Comment: yes  WLAN is active, I tried already a connection via IP address but it also do not work

Answer (score 0):

Use with your local **server IP address**:

```
http://192.155.1.66
```

or, if its running on specific port then,

```
http://192.155.1.66:3001
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

had you given the following permission in the manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`